# Animation for Bootstrap-columns changing width and position in row

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a webapplication using React and Bootsrap in the frontend. There multiple Bootstrap-columns that can be expanded, shown in the CodeSandbox below. I would like to animate these as they change width and position in the row.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7jmp1275z6

The animation could be just about anything, as long as the columns don't just instantly teleport up and down. Sliding up and down or left and right are both fine.

Answer (score 0):

For further question, please give information to what have you done by yourself, so people will help you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/p7z2m6vmp7

Just add some transition like you'd do to any simple CSS transition.

Here, I'd give different animation to different box, feel free to experiment with the cubic-bezier! (the css also have `ease` and `ease-in-out` by default)

```
.box:nth-child(1) {
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
```

Comment: I suppose I am not all that good at asking questions. Or expressing myself in text. The part that is really messing with my mind is adding an animation when the columns snap to positions vertically. But thanks for this information, might help with what I have so far.

Comment: well it's fine, I'm not that senior around here so I can understand that!

And for more question about styling like this, you're better off using css tag since it's not reactjs problem, so more people will be likely to help.